# Is there any way to resize a tkinter button?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Is there any way to resize button size in python tkinter?
I have tried to resize button size in python 3.7.2 tkinter by using `button.config(width = 100, hight = 100)`, but it didn't work properly. Is there any way to resize button?

I use Python 3.7.2 and Windows 10.

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()

#*** Settings ***#
win.title("Project_title")
win.geometry("660x450")
win.resizable(False, False)
wall = tk.PhotoImage(file = "pictures_gui.gif")
wall_label = tk.Label(image = wall)
#*** Settings ***#

#*** Test code ***#
def click_me():
    button.configure(text="** I have been clicked")

button = tk.Button(win,text = "Click me!",command=click_me)
button.grid(column=1, row=0)
button.config(width = 100,hight = 100)
#*** Test code ***#

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: What does "didn't work properly" mean? What did it do, and how was it different than what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to set the button size in pixels. The button size defaults to characters when the button displays text but no image. To get the size to be pixels you have to display an image in the button. See the example below:

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry("660x450")
win.resizable(False, False)

def click_me():
    button.configure(text="** I have been clicked")

# Create a transparent image to allow Button size in pixels
pixel = tk.PhotoImage(file='images/pixel.png')

button = tk.Button(win, text="Click me!", command=click_me,
                   image=pixel, compound='center')
button.grid(column=1, row=0)
button.config(width=100, height=100)    # Config size in pixels

win.mainloop()
```

The `pixel.png` image is 1x1 pixel and has transparent color.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have solved this problem by using your code.